# Convert mysql query to laravel with abs function

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following query in mysql:

```
select *  from matches m where pick_score<>0 order by ABS(pick_score) DESC
```

I want to write it in laravel and I tried:

```
$matches = $matches->where('pick_score', '<>', '0');
$matches = $matches->orderByRaw('ABS(pick_score)', 'DESC');
```

Unfortunately, it does not work as expected. The result of the mysql queries has the following values: 1222.9396, -914.6969, 880.8959 and the laravel result has: 2.628662, -36.759403, -103.41754, etc.
Can anyone help me with the right query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [orderByRaw()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#raw-methods) the 2nd params is for bindings not direction. You just need to include the direction in the actual sql string:

```
$matches = DB::table('matches')
    ->where('pick_score', '<>', 0)
    ->orderByRaw('ABS(pick_score) DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: @Maria1995 Glad I could help! :) Thanks.

Comment: it will let me do that in 3 minutes :D I will, of course. thank you again